# Filebeat - parse fields from message line

Tags: elasticsearch, filebeat

I am using Filebeat to ship log data from my local txt files into Elasticsearch, and
I want to add some fields from the `message` line to the event - like timestamp and log level. For example here is one of my log lines:

`2016-09-22 13:51:02,877 INFO 'start myservice service'`

My question is: Can I do that by Filebeat -> Elasticsearch or must I go through Logstash?

Comment: You could conceivably use the dissect processor within filebeat: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/dissect.html

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can use Filebeat -> Elasticsearch if you make use of the [Ingest Node](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/filebeat/current/configuring-ingest-node.html) feature in Elasticsearch 5.0. Otherwise, yes, you need to use [Logstash](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/beats/libbeat/current/logstash-installation.html#logstash-setup).

In both cases you would use a [grok filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-grok.html) to parse the `message` line into structured data. Also you'll want to use a [`date`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-filters-date.html) to parse and normalize the date.